# how to upload file to server / django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, file-upload, view

Thanks to stack overflow, I implemented loading a file in views, but how to make sure that the file gets to the server and data appears in the database. If I upload a file through the admin panel, then everything works fine.
I'm testing with postman. Thank you)

```
# urls.py
path('api/v1/UploadDataset/', UploadDataset.as_view()),
```

```
# models.py
class Datasets(models.Model):
    create_at = models.IntegerField(max_length=50) 
    user = models.IntegerField(max_length=50) 
    name_dataset = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    link_dataset =  models.FileField (upload_to=datasets_filename)
```

```
# serializers.py

class UploadDatasetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Datasets
        fields =  '__all__'
```

```
# views.py
class UploadDataset(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser )
    #parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]    

    def put(self, request,  format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
            
        # do some stuff with uploaded file ???
        return Response(status=204)
```

Comment: Hello, what is the type of your `file_obj` at this moment ?